# Why Magento 2 `addForeignKey` function does not have `onUpdate` and how to add it while adding foreign key

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, foreign-key

I have started with Magento 2 setup scripts and I found one small change with Magento's `addForeignKey` function parameters.
In Magento 1, the arguments for the function is like,

```
public function addForeignKey($fkName, $column, $refTable, $refColumn, $onDelete = null, $onUpdate = null)
```

There is an option for defining what to do on update of referenced table row,

While in Magento 2, the arguments for the same function is like,

```
public function addForeignKey($fkName, $column, $refTable, $refColumn, $onDelete = null)
```

They have remove `onUpdate` argument.
Does anyone have any idea about why they did that??
Also can anyone guide me what to do if I want to add `onUpdate` action for foreign key?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this acknowledged Github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1728), this is actually by design:

> Hi, this is deliberate restriction, to achieve better compliance with other possible database engines.
>   But you can implement actions like "ON UPDATE" on application level. In this case your code will be compatible with Magento SPI ( events, interceptors, e.t.c).